# Unexpected Termination of process

Tags: java

Im trying to put new Values into Arrays but for some reason at point where the scanner waits for my input the process terminates.

The relevant part:

Arrays:

```
public static String folders[] = { "Ordner 1", "Ordner 2", "Ordner 3", "Ordner 4", "Ordner 5" };
public static BigDecimal value[] = new BigDecimal[5];
```

And the void:

```
public static void session_start() {
    Scanner scanner = new Scanner(System.in);
    System.out.println("");
    System.out.println("Bitte gib einen Befehl ein: ");
    String eingabe = scanner.nextLine();
    switch (eingabe) {
    case "exit": {
        System.exit(1);
    }
    case "neuer Ordner": {
        BigDecimal new_value = new BigDecimal("0");
        System.out.println("Name des Ordners?");
        String name = scanner.nextLine();
        System.out.println("Der wievielte Ordner soll es sein (maximal 5)?");
        int order = scanner.nextInt();
        try {
            System.out.println("Möchtest du einen Betrag zuweisen?");
            String ja_nein = scanner.nextLine();
            if(ja_nein.equals("Ja") || ja_nein.equals("ja")) {
                System.out.println("Bitte gib den Betrag an: ");
                new_value = scanner.nextBigDecimal();
            }
        } catch (Exception f) {
            f.printStackTrace();
        }
        folders[order - 1] = name;
        value[order - 1] = new_value;
    }
    }
}
```

If i come to the line:

```
System.out.println("Möchtest du einen Betrag zuweisen?");
String ja_nein = scanner.nextLine();
```

The process terminates.

The try {} was just for testing purposes and my own search for the bug but i couldn´t find it.

Comment: What does the `printStackTrace()` say?

Comment: [Be careful](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13102045/scanner-is-skipping-nextline-after-using-next-or-nextfoo) when using `nextLine()` after `nextInt()`.

Comment: What is the value of `eingabe` when the process terminates?

Comment: You should follow the Java Naming Conventions: variable names and method names are written in camelCase. That means no underscores, i.e. `new_value` should be `newValue`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As @TiiJ7 said in the comments. You must [be careful](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13102045/scanner-is-skipping-nextline-after-using-next-or-nextfoo) when collecting both ints and strings from the same Scanner because of the fact that nextInt() leaves the `\n` on the buffer, it will cause any nextLine's afterwards to instantly return empty. Most seasoned Java developers, actually use 2 Scanners one for numbers, and the other for strings.

For example:

```
Scanner stringInput = new Scanner(System.in);
Scanner numInput = new Scanner(System.in);
int valueToScan = numInput.nextInt();
String nextLine = stringInput.nextLine();
```

In your situation the line:`int order = scanner.nextInt();` is leaving a `\n` character in the Scanner's internal buffer. Therefore, when `nextLine` gets called, it immedietly returns with an empty string, because it immedietly hits the remaining `\n` character.